# SQL return multiple non-null values with highest index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database:

**Customers**:

```
CustID  CustName
======  ========
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
```

**Transactions**:

```
TransID  CustID  InvoiceTotal  LoyaltyPointsEarned
=======  ======  ============  ===================
1        1       300           25
2        2       NULL          10
3        3       100           10
4        2       200           25
5        1       NULL          100
6        3       120           NULL
```

Transactions are inserted in chronological order (higher ID = more recent order); a transaction allows either InvoiceTotal or LoyaltyPointsEarned to be NULL, but not both.

I want to get the most recent non-null invoice total AND (this is the tricky bit) most recent non-null loyalty points earned for all customers, with this information displayed on the same row for each customer:

```
CustID  CustName  LatestInvoiceTotal  LatestLoyaltyPointsEarned
1       A         300                 100
2       B         200                 25
3       C         120                 10
```

The following query gives the latest invoice total:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CustID, CustName, LatestInvoiceTotal, LatestLoyaltyPointsEarned
FROM 
    Customers
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         CustID, InvoiceTotal AS LatestInvoiceTotal, TransID 
     FROM 
         Transactions 
     GROUP BY 
         CustID, InvoiceTotal, TransID) CustomerTransactions ON Customers.CustID = CustomerTransactions.CustID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         CustID, MAX(TransID) AS MaxTransID 
     FROM 
         Transactions 
     WHERE 
         InvoiceTotal IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY 
         CustID) MaxTransactionIDs ON Customers.CustID = MaxTransactionIDs.CustID AND CustomerTransactions.TransID = MaxTransactionIDs.MaxTransID
```

How can this be extended to do the same for LoyaltyPointsEarned, without duplicating customer records in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is having two subqueries retrieving that information.

```
select CustID, CustName, 
       (select top 1 InvoiceTotal
        from Transactions
        where Transactions.CustID = Customers.CustID and InvoiceTotal is not null
        order by TransID desc) as LatestInvoiceTotal,
       (select top 1 LoyaltyPointsEarned
        from Transactions
        where Transactions.CustID = Customers.CustID and LoyaltyPointsEarnedis not null
        order by TransID desc) as LatestLoyaltyPointsEarned               
from Customers
```

But as subqueries could importantly degrade your performance, you just have to be sure to have a multiple index on Transactions over CustID, TransID descending, so those subqueries would be optimized.

Comment: This works a treat, thanks. I had to replace descending with desc (SQL Server 2008 r2).

Comment: Fixed :-). I'm still getting used to SQL Server particularities.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query to get desired result.. MAX() OVER() function can be used in such situation.

```
;WITH cte_1
AS
 (SELECT a.CustID  ,a.CustName,MAX(InvoiceTotal ) OVER( Partition by a.CustID  Order by TransID  desc )LatestInvoiceTotal  
        ,MAX(LoyaltyPointsEarned ) OVER( Partition by a.CustID  Order by TransID  desc )LatestLoyaltyPointsEarned
        FROM Customers a
            JOIN Transactions b
                ON  a.CustID  =b.CustID )
 SELECT DISTINCT *
 FROM cte_1
 WHERE LatestInvoiceTotal IS NOT NULL AND LatestLoyaltyPointsEarned is NOT NULL
```

Here is the test scenario :

```
DROP TABLE #Customers

DROP TABLE #Transactions


 CREATE TABLE #Customers
 (
 CustId INT,
 CustName VARCHAR(50)
 )

  CREATE TABLE #Transactions
 (
 TransID   INT,
 CustID   INT,
 InvoiceTotal  INT,
 LoyaltyPointsEarned INT
 )

 INSERT INTO #Customers
 VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D')

 INSERT INTO #Transactions
 VALUES (1,1,300,25),(2,2,NULL,10),(3,3,100,10),(4,2,200,25),(5,1,NULL,100),(6,3,120,NULL)


;WITH cte_1
AS
 (SELECT a.CustID  ,a.CustName,MAX(InvoiceTotal ) OVER( Partition by a.CustID  Order by TransID  desc )LatestInvoiceTotal  
        ,MAX(LoyaltyPointsEarned ) OVER( Partition by a.CustID  Order by TransID  desc )LatestLoyaltyPointsEarned
        FROM #Customers a
            JOIN #Transactions b
                ON  a.CustID  =b.CustID )
 SELECT DISTINCT *
 FROM cte_1
 WHERE LatestInvoiceTotal IS NOT NULL AND LatestLoyaltyPointsEarned is NOT NULL
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use window funtion.

You will need 2 subquery though :

```
with tmp as (
 select custId, 
  InvoiceTotal, 
  row_number() over(partition by custId order by TransId desc) as rnk
 from Transactions
 where InvoiceTotal is not null)
select *
from tmp
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pair of joins seems to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CustID, CustName, LatestInvoiceTotal, LatestLoyaltyPointsEarned
FROM 
    Customers
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         CustID, InvoiceTotal AS LatestInvoiceTotal, TransID 
     FROM 
         Transactions 
     GROUP BY 
         CustID, InvoiceTotal, TransID) CustomerTransactions ON Customers.CustID = CustomerTransactions.CustID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         CustID, MAX(TransID) AS MaxTransID 
     FROM 
         Transactions 
     WHERE 
         InvoiceTotal IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY 
         CustID) MaxTransactionIDs ON Customers.CustID = MaxTransactionIDs.CustID AND CustomerTransactions.TransID = MaxTransactionIDs.MaxTransID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         CustID, LoyaltyPointsEarned AS LatestLoyaltyPointsEarned, TransID 
     FROM 
         Transactions 
     GROUP BY 
         CustID, LoyaltyPointsEarned, TransID) CustomerTransactions2 ON Customers.CustID = CustomerTransactions2.CustID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         CustID, MAX(TransID) AS MaxTransID 
     FROM 
         Transactions 
     WHERE 
         LoyaltyPointsEarned IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY 
         CustID) MaxTransactionIDs2 ON Customers.CustID = MaxTransactionIDs2.CustID AND CustomerTransactions2.TransID = MaxTransactionIDs2.MaxTransID
```

Comment: This only returns customers that have both at least one invoice value and one loyalty points value. Use marc's answer above to get the nulls as well.